# Win10 - How to pipe the output from one command as an argument of another to check file hash?

Tags: powershell, hash, compare, command-line-tool

Lets say that I need to verify the md5 hash of a file against the hash provided by the website.

I use `certutil -hashfile .\amazon-corretto-11.0.10.9.1-windows-x64.msi md5` or `Get-FileHash -Path .\amazon-corretto-11.0.10.9.1-windows-x64.msi -Algorithm md5` in powershell to get the hash, then I look at the hash from the download website, and compare them letter by letter. Is there a way to let the command line do the comparison?

I tried `certutil -hashfile .\amazon-corretto-11.0.10.9.1-windows-x64.msi md5 | echo == "website_hash"`, but it didn't work.

Solutions in command line and powershell are both welcomed.

Comment: Comparing hashes is a common thing with lots of samples all over the web. You are mixing the command line (cmd.exe) and trying to use a PowerShell PipeLine. what you are doing is not work, because if you are doing this in a PowerShell instance, that command is wrong. The pipe` '|'` symbol means different things in `cmd.exe` vs `powershell.exe`. When you call executables from PowerShell, the executable is in control.   Use the Powershell help files for `Get-help -Name Get-FileHash -Full` adn `Compare-Object`; use case in PowerShell proper.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include an answer. You can post an answer to your question as a separate post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Continuing from my comment](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27PowerShell%20file%20hash%20compare%27&t=h_&ia=web). Try this:

```
Get-FileHash -Path 'D:\temp\book1.txt' -Algorithm MD5 | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
Algorithm Hash                             Path             
--------- ----                             ----             
MD5       D572724F26BD600773F708AB264BE45B D:\temp\book1.txt
#>


$CompareObjectSplat = @{
    DifferenceObject = (Get-FileHash -Path 'D:\temp\book1.txt' -Algorithm MD5).Hash
    ReferenceObject  = (Get-FileHash -Path 'D:\temp\book1.txt' -Algorithm MD5).Hash
}
Compare-Object @compareObjectSplat -IncludeEqual

# Results
<#
InputObject                      SideIndicator
-----------                      -------------
D572724F26BD600773F708AB264BE45B == 
#>

# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-FileHash).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-FileHash).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-FileHash -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-FileHash -Full
Get-help -Name Get-FileHash -Online


(Get-Command -Name Compare-Object).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Compare-Object).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Compare-Object -Examples
Get-help -Name Compare-Object -Full
Get-help -Name Compare-Object -Online
```

Tagging on to this as per mklement0's helpful response to you and your follow-up query.

```
# Command line - executable
(certutil -hashfile 'D:\temp\book1.txt' md5)
# Results
<#
MD5 hash of D:\temp\book1.txt:
d572724f26bd600773f708ab264be45b
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
#>

(certutil -hashfile 'D:\temp\book1.txt' md5)[1] -eq (certutil -hashfile 'D:\temp\book1.txt' md5)[1]
# Results
<#
True
#>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply enclose a command in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), if you want its output to act as an operand to an operator, such as `-eq`, the [equality operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-eq):

```
(certutil -hashfile .\amazon-corretto-11.0.10.9.1-windows-x64.msi md5)[1] -eq "website_hash"
```

Note: [postanote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9132707/postanote) points out that `certutil` outputs *mutiple* lines, with the hash of interest being on the *second* line, which the `[1]` index access returns, based on PowerShell returning the output lines from *external programs* as an *array of strings*.

Comment: Thanks, @postanote (I have no access to `certutil` at the moment) - answer updated accordingly.

Comment: @fall: As for why you saw no output: with an _array_ as the LHS, `-eq` acts as a _filter_, i.e. returns the _subarray_ of _matching items_ rather than single `$true` or `$false` value. Receiving no output means that your RHS operand matched no element of the LHS array, which in turn implies that the hashes don't match.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @postanote and @mklement0's answers, here are 2 powpershell one-liners to very file hash, both ignores cases.

certutil:

```
(certutil -hashfile ./amazon-corretto-11.0.10.9.1-windows-x64.msi MD5)[1] -eq ("EE569A19016F233B2050CC11219EBBFD")
```

Get-FileHash:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-FileHash -Path '.\amazon-corretto-11.0.10.9.1-windows-x64.msi' -Algorithm MD5).Hash -DifferenceObject ("EE569A19016F233B2050CC11219EBBFD") -IncludeEqual
```